# Cantilever Beam Height versus Deflection

Tags: structure, analysis, finite-element-analysis, ansys

I have a problem whereby in a LINEAR analysis, a cantilever is vertically bent through a tip load.

A parametric study is required between...

Change in Tip Deflection (dZ)   versus   Change in Beam Height (dH)

I want to see the SENESITIVITY is more at higher deflection values or vice versa. Thats to say, same height change brings more change in cantilever deflection for higher beam deflections ?

Best regards,
Rehan

Answer (score 1):

The deflection of a cantilever beam subjected to a point load has a [closed form solution.](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/cantilever-beams-d_1848.html)

δB = F L^3 / (3 E I)

It's not clear from your question if "height" means the beam thickness.  If yes, substitute into the formula for `I` and take the derivative w.r.t. thickness to get the closed form solution.

It helps to know the answer before embarking on FEA.